# djongo, unable to connect to remote db on cloud.mongodb.com

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mongodb, djongo

i think below setting will work for the djongo to connect to the remote mongodb on mongodb.com but, the error message shows its still trying to connect to the localhost

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-name/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
}
```

below is the error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/introspection.py", line 47, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.list_collection_names()
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 856, in list_collection_names
    for result in self.list_collections(session=session, **kwargs)]
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 819, in list_collections
    _cmd, read_pref, session)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1454, in _retryable_read
    read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1253, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 235, in select_server
    address))
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 193, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I GOT THE SOLUTION**

I adopted following approach >

so, behind the scene the djongo uses -> pymongo

and pymongo's default configuration are

```py
class MongoClient(common.BaseObject):
    HOST = "localhost"   # here HOST has the hardcoded value
    PORT = 27017
```

which lies in following file

**venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py**

replace the harcoded value of HOST to something like

```py
HOST = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-name/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

**ADDITIONALLY**
We can set the environment variable if we want

```py
HOST = os.getenv('MONGO_DB_URL')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have met your problem before. In my case, I run django & mongodb inside containers. And I found that whatever setting I set inside `setting.py`, the djongo(they use pymongo behind) just ignore my setting.

For others seeking for the solution, you may want to check your syntax in `setting.py` which should look like below:

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'your-db-name',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'host-name or ip address',
                'port': port_number,
                'username': 'db-username',
                'password': 'password',
                'authSource': 'db-name',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
            },

         .......
}
```

[Detail from djongo document](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/djongo-deep-dive/)

You can see the host, user, password fields are all under 'CLIENT' , which is different with the default syntax described by Django. So maybe most people get confused here and stuck at this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings.py file and use below Database settngs

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True
        'NAME': 'your-db-name',
        'HOST': 'host-name or ip address',
        'PORT': port_number,
        'USER': 'db-username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'AUTH_SOURCE': 'db-name',
        'AUTH_MECHANISM': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
    }
```

Please also check out this article for connection between django and mongo db.

https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/how-to-use-django-with-mongodb-40ba36a21124

I personally recommend you please use pycharm. In Pycharm  you can test your connection. So that you can get more clear image of whole scenario.

I use remote database in django. you can see in the below picture
[image]

Comment: thanks, what should i put for 'AUTH_SOURCE' key in DATABASES object

Comment: You are welcome!Sounds nice, your problem has been resolved.